# How to make data binding work with xml attributes?

Tags: android, viewmodel, android-databinding, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

I'm setting up my `Edittext` and `CheckBox` to hook with my view model. I've already setup the variables `isActive` and `currentValue` on my ViewModel, and I want to initialize their values to the xml so that when the user arrives at the Fragment, the current values are also set to the form fields.

I've already tried adding `android:checked="@{viewModel.isActive}"` to the `CheckBox`, and `android:text="@{viewModel.currentValue}"` to the `EditText`, however it produces no result.

Right now, my workaround is initializing the form field values through the Fragment:

```
viewModel.isActive.observe(this, Observer {
    it?.let {
        binding.checkBox.isChecked = it
    }
})
viewModel.currentValue.observe(this, Observer {
    it?.let {
        binding.editText.setText(it.toString())
    }
})
```

Here's my code:

```
ViewModel.kt

val isActive = Transformations.map(currentEntity) {
    it.value?.isActive == 1
}

val currentValue = Transformations.map(currentEntity) {
    it.value?.currentValue
}

private var currentEntity = MutableLiveData<Entity?>()
init {
    initializeCurrentEntity()
}

private fun initializeCurrentEntity() {
    uiScope.launch {
        currentEntity.value = getCurrentEntityById(id)
    }
}
```

```
layout.xml

<layout ...>
    <data>
        <variable name="viewModel"
                  type="com.example.app.ViewModel"/>
    </data>
    ...
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout ... >
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText  
            ...
            android:text="@{viewModel.currentValue}"
            ...
            />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
    ...
    <CheckBox
        ...
        android:checked="@{viewModel.isActive}" />
</layout>
```

My desired result is that, when the `viewModel` has already initialized the `currentEntity` and updated the `isActive` and `currentValue`, it would also reflect in the xml. I think that the actual outputs as of now is null for both the `currentValue` and `isActive`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that I have forgotten to set the LifecycleOwner to the data binding. I have fixed it with `binding.setLifecycleOwner(this)` on my Fragment.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing the same thing twice in  a wrong way.

Here is the two options you have. **Do only one of them.**

> Option1: bind viewModel and databinding will automatically observe it

```
<layout ...>
    <data>
        <variable name="viewModel"
                  type="com.example.app.ViewModel"/>
    </data>
    ...
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout ... >
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText  
            ...
            android:text="@{viewModel.currentValue}"
            ...
            />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
    ...
    <CheckBox
        ...
        android:checked="@{viewModel.isActive}" />
</layout>
```

You need to pass viewModel to the binding:

```
binding.viewModel = authenticationViewModel
```

also don't forget to set lifecycle owner:

```
binding.lifecycleOwner = this
```

If you are going to choose this option then **REMOVE** this lines from your code:

```
viewModel.isActive.observe(this, Observer {
    it?.let {
        binding.checkBox.isChecked = it
    }
})
viewModel.currentValue.observe(this, Observer {
    it?.let {
        binding.editText.setText(it.toString())
    }
})
```

> Option2: manually observer live data

```
viewModel.isActive.observe(this, Observer {
    it?.let {
        binding.checkBox.isChecked = it
    }
})
viewModel.currentValue.observe(this, Observer {
    it?.let {
        binding.editText.setText(it.toString())
    }
})
```

If you are going to choose this option then **REMOVE** this lines from your xml:

```
<data>
    <variable name="viewModel"
              type="com.example.app.ViewModel"/>
</data>
```

and

```
android:checked="@{viewModel.isActive}"
```

and

```
android:text="@{viewModel.currentValue}"
```

Comment: Yes. Hooking an Observer object is my workaround when I still couldn't get the data binding to work, but I didn't use both of them along side each other. Setting the lifecycle owner fixed the code for me, which I have forgotten to do in the first place...

Comment: Nice.. I mistakenly thought you mixed these two solutions.